# Animate new ListView entries in Javafx

Tags: java, listview, animation, javafx, javafx-8

### The Problem

Hi,

I'm trying to write an application where every new entry in a ListView gets animated. Here is my code:

```
public class BookCell extends ListCell<Book>
{
    private Text text;
    private HBox h;
    
    public BookCell()
    {
        this.text = new Text();
        this.h = new HBox();
        this.h.getChildren().add(text);
        super.getStyleClass().add("book-list-cell");
        super.itemProperty().addListener((obs,oldv,newv)->{
            if(newv != null )
            {
                if(getIndex() == this.getListView().getItems().size()-1 )
                {
                    //why does this get called twice for each update?
                    System.out.println("isbn = "+newv.getIsbn().get() + "   lastIndexOf=" + this.getListView().getItems().lastIndexOf(newv)+"    Index="+getIndex()+"   size="+this.getListView().getItems().size());
                    runAnimation();
                }
            }
            
        });
        this.getChildren().add(h);
    }
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Book item, boolean empty)
    {
         super.updateItem(item, empty);
         if(!empty)
             super.setGraphic(h);
         text.setText(item == null ? "" : item.getIsbn().get());
         
    }
    
    public void runAnimation()
    {
        FadeTransition f = new FadeTransition();
        f.setFromValue(0);
        f.setToValue(1);
        f.setNode(this);
        f.play();
    }
}
```

I've tried to add a listener to the itemProperty, but I get some strange behavior. Firstly, the listener fires twice each time I add an entry:
[image]
which results in the animation playing twice. This can be a little awkward to watch even though it is hardly noticeable in this case.

Furthermore, after the list starts scrolling, the animation is *sometimes* repeated for a visible entry:
[image]

To be completely honest, I wouldn't necessarily mind the animation repeating if an item *gets visible again*, but as it stands, it is very unreliable which cells get animated.

I know that the cells are virtually controlled and get reused over time. But I'm having a hard time to find a reliable way to determine if a nonempty cell appears on the screen.

### The Questions

1. Why is the listener firing twice?
2. What is the best way to observe the appearance/disappearance of a cell on the screen
3. Is there a better way to add animations to a ListView?

### The complete code

It might be helpful, so here are my css and main files.

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application 
{
    static int newBookIndex = 1;        
    public static final ObservableList<Book> data =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        try 
        {
            GridPane myPane = (GridPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("quotes.fxml"));
            ListView<Book> lv = (ListView<Book>) myPane.getChildren().get(0);   
            Button addButton = (Button) myPane.getChildren().get(1);
            addButton.setText("Add Book");
            addButton.setOnAction((event)->{
            data.add(new Book(String.valueOf(newBookIndex++),"test"));
            });
            lv.setEditable(true);
            data.addAll(
                     new Book("123","Hugo"),
                     new Book("456","Harry Potter")
                );
                  
            lv.setItems(data);
            lv.setCellFactory((param)->return new BookCell());
            Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);
            myScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

application.css (based on https://github.com/privatejava/javafx-listview-animation)

```
.book-list-cell:odd{

    -fx-background-image: url('./wooden2.png') ,url('./gloss.png');
    -fx-background-repeat: repeat,no-repeat;
}
.book-list-cell:empty {
     -fx-background-image: url('./gloss.png');
     -fx-background-repeat: repeat;
}

.book-list-cell {
    -fx-font-size:45px;
    -fx-font-family: 'Segoe Script';
}
.book-list-cell:selected,.book-list-cell:selected:hover{
    -fx-border-color:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent,rgb(22,22,22,1));
    -fx-border-width:2 2 2 10px;
    -fx-effect:innershadow( three-pass-box,#764b0c,30,0.3,0,0);
}
.book-list-cell:hover{
    -fx-border-color:rgb(255,255,255,0.7);
    -fx-border-width:1 1 1 10px;
}

.book-list-cell{
    -fx-background-image: url('./wooden.png') ,url('./gloss.png');
    -fx-background-repeat: repeat,no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position:left top;
    -fx-background-size: auto,100% 40%;
}
```

Comment: Just a side-comment. I did not know you could use the headings like the ones you used in your questions until now. Thanks for showing that! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the reason for the double firing of the listener, I've done some debugging, following the `layoutChildren` calls.

Long story short: for every click on the `Add Book` button, there are not two, but three changes in `itemProperty()`. To find out, add some printing to console on the listener and the `updateItem` method:

```
itemProperty().addListener((obs,oldv,newv)->{
    System.out.println("change: "+getIndex()+", newv "+(newv != null?newv.getIsbn():"null")+", oldv: "+(oldv != null?oldv.getIsbn():"null"));
}

protected void updateItem(Book item, boolean empty){
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        System.out.println("update item: "+(item!=null?item.getIsbn():"null"));
}
```

For the first book "123", this is the trace:

```
update item: null
change: 0, newv 123, oldv: null
update item: 123
change: -1, newv null, oldv: 123
update item: null
update item: null
change: 0, newv 123, oldv: null
update item: 123
```

The first change happens as expected due to the creation of a new cell. But once it's created, this is followed by a call to `VirtualFlow.releaseCell()` with index -1, and finally *all* the cells are rebuilt all over again with `addLeadingCells()` and `addTrailingCells()` in `VirtualFlow.layoutChildren()`.

So by design, these calls can't be avoided, what means the animation shouldn't be in the listener if you want to make sure it's only called once.

**ANIMATION**

I've come with a solution that implies getting the cell and run the animation:

```
addButton.setOnAction((event)->{
    data.add(new Book(String.valueOf(newBookIndex++),"test"));

    VirtualFlow vf=(VirtualFlow)lv.lookup(".virtual-flow");
    BookCell cell = (BookCell)vf.getCell(lv.getItems().size()-1);
    cell.runAnimation();
});
```

This is not very advisable since uses `VirtualFlow`, private API.

This can be avoided by looking for the CSS selector `indexed-cells` instead:

```
addButton.setOnAction((event)->{
    data.add(new Book(String.valueOf(newBookIndex),"test"));

    lv.lookupAll(".indexed-cell").stream()
            .map(n->(BookCell)n)
            .filter(c->c.getBook().getIsbn().equals(String.valueOf(newBookIndex)))
            .findFirst().ifPresent(BookCell::runAnimation);
    newBookIndex++;
});
```

Note that since we're using lookups, the event handler for the button should be added after the stage is shown.

**EDIT**

There are weird problems reported by the OP with scrolling. I'm not sure if this is a bug, but the top cell is animated instead of the bottom one.

To solve this issue I've come with this workaround, removing `BookCell` animation, and creating one for the cell, using `VirtualFlow` to get the cell and scroll if necessary.

First we try to find if the scrollbars are not visible: we use the our fade transition. But if we have scrollbars, now we need to call `show()` to scroll to the last cell. A short `PauseTransition` does the trick before launching the fade transition.

```
addButton.setOnAction((event)->{
    addButton.setDisable(true);
    data.add(new Book(String.valueOf(newBookIndex),"test"));

    VirtualFlow vf=(VirtualFlow)lv.lookup(".virtual-flow");
    if(!lv.lookup(".scroll-bar").isVisible()){
        FadeTransition f = new FadeTransition();
        f.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
        f.setFromValue(0);
        f.setToValue(1);
        f.setNode(vf.getCell(lv.getItems().size()-1));
        f.setOnFinished(t->{
            newBookIndex++;
            addButton.setDisable(false);                        
        });
        f.play();
    } else {
        PauseTransition p = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(20));
        p.setOnFinished(e->{
            vf.getCell(lv.getItems().size()-1).setOpacity(0);
            vf.show(lv.getItems().size()-1);
            FadeTransition f = new FadeTransition();
            f.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
            f.setFromValue(0);
            f.setToValue(1);
            f.setNode(vf.getCell(lv.getItems().size()-1));
            f.setOnFinished(t->{
                newBookIndex++;
                addButton.setDisable(false);                        
            });
            f.play();
        });
        p.play();
    }
});
```

**UPDATED CODE**

Finally, this is all the code I've used:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private int newBookIndex = 2;        
    public final ObservableList<Book> data =  FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Book("123","Hugo"), new Book("456","Harry Potter"));
    private final ListView<Book> lv = new ListView<>();   

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button addButton = new Button("Add Book");

        lv.setCellFactory(param->new BookCell());
        lv.setItems(data);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(new VBox(10,lv,addButton), 200, 200);
        myScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
        primaryStage.show();

        addButton.setOnAction((event)->{
            addButton.setDisable(true);
            data.add(new Book(String.valueOf(newBookIndex),"test"));

            VirtualFlow vf=(VirtualFlow)lv.lookup(".virtual-flow");
            if(!lv.lookup(".scroll-bar").isVisible()){
                FadeTransition f = new FadeTransition();
                f.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
                f.setFromValue(0);
                f.setToValue(1);
                f.setNode(vf.getCell(lv.getItems().size()-1));
                f.setOnFinished(t->{
                    newBookIndex++;
                    addButton.setDisable(false);                        
                });
                f.play();
            } else {
                PauseTransition p = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(20));
                p.setOnFinished(e->{
                    vf.getCell(lv.getItems().size()-1).setOpacity(0);
                    vf.show(lv.getItems().size()-1);
                    FadeTransition f = new FadeTransition();
                    f.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
                    f.setFromValue(0);
                    f.setToValue(1);
                    f.setNode(vf.getCell(lv.getItems().size()-1));
                    f.setOnFinished(t->{
                        newBookIndex++;
                        addButton.setDisable(false);                        
                    });
                    f.play();
                });
                p.play();
            }
        });
    }

    class BookCell extends ListCell<Book>{
        private final Text text = new Text();
        private final HBox h = new HBox(text);

        {
            getStyleClass().add("book-list-cell");
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Book item, boolean empty){
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if(item!=null && !empty){
                text.setText(item.getIsbn());
                setGraphic(h);
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(null);
            }
        }
    }

    class Book {
        private Book(String isbn, String name) {
            this.isbn.set(isbn);
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public void setName(String value) {
            name.set(value);
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        private final StringProperty isbn = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public String getIsbn() {
            return isbn.get();
        }

        public void setIsbn(String value) {
            isbn.set(value);
        }

        public StringProperty isbnProperty() {
            return isbn;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't even consider the lookup approach. But I have some Problems with this solution. May you have a look at this screenshot:
http://postimg.org/image/tj3f42j23/
as you can see, after the scrolling begins, the top cells get animated instead of the bottom ones.

Comment: That was a really hard issue to solve. After multiply attempts, I've come with a workaround that's working for me. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Yeah it solves the problem. To be honest, I thought that adding a simple animation to a ListView wouldn't be that complicated and hacky. Is it really such an uncommon thing to do?

Comment: For a single cell it is because of the virtual flow... But if you apply animation to all of cells is simpler. Have a look at this [post](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2013/09/07/listcell-animation-listview-javafx/). It plays the animation for all cells on the `updateItem()` method.

Comment: Yeah this post was my starting point. But when I run his example ([available on github](https://github.com/privatejava/javafx-listview-animation)), my cells are flipping all over the place, not like in the video. It seems broken, at least in Java 8.

Comment: For me is running fine (Windows 64 bits, JDK 8u25). But it's too overloaded anyway for a regular use.

Comment: Ah! I checked my JDK and it was 8u05. After updating to 8u25, the example runs fine too!

Comment: I tried this method. But for me no animation is shown for the cells before the scrollbar is visible. It works just fine after the scrollbar appears.

Comment: I also have the same problem @Ivantha! Not sure what the problem is

Comment: @Ivantha This answer is quite old to do a follow up over comments. Can you please post a new question with what you have done and refer to this one?