# Gluon Mobile Cardpane UI Enhancements: Cardcell Generation/Deletion & Cardpane Styling

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to create a cardpane with custom HBox CardCells.

**Issue #1**

How do I set the background of this CardPane? I want it to be transparent, but it won't change from this grey color. I have tried adding styling to the node directly as well as add a custom stylesheet. I have also tried the **setBackground** method:

[image]

**Issue #2**

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130679/animate-new-listview-entries-in-javafx) SO post, I was able to add an animation for cell generation in which it fades in upwards. However, in random card inserts, different cells lose the node that I have embedded in that cell. I don't know if this is because of the recycling concept of these cards (based on Gluon docs) or what:

[image]

**Issue #3**

I created functionality such that the user can delete the cards by swiping left. However, the same issue from Issue #2 arises, but to an even greater extent in which the entire cell is missing but still taking space. If I have only one cell and swipe left, it works all the time. However when I have more than one cell (for example I have 3 cells and I delete the 2nd cell), things get broken, event handlers for cells get removed, swiping left on one cell starts the animation on a cell below it, etc. Is there a way I can perform this functionality or is my best bet to just get rid of the CardPane and use a combination of VBox and HBox elements?

```
private void addToCardPane(CustomCard newCard) {

    ObservableList<Node> items = cardpane.getItems();
    boolean override = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < cardpane.getItems().size(); i++) {
        CustomCard box = (CustomCard) items.get(i);
        if (box.checkEquality(newCard)) {
            box.increaseNumber(newCard);
            override = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (override == false) {
        cardpane.getItems().add(newCard);
        cardpane.layout();
        VirtualFlow vf = (VirtualFlow) cardpane.lookup(".virtual-flow");
        Node cell = vf.getCell(cardpane.getItems().size() - 1);
        cell.setTranslateX(0);
        cell.setOpacity(1.0);
        if (!cardpane.lookup(".scroll-bar").isVisible()) {
            FadeInUpTransition f = new FadeInUpTransition(cell);
            f.setRate(2);
            f.play();
        } else {
            PauseTransition p = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(20));
            p.setOnFinished(e -> {
                vf.getCell(cardpane.getItems().size() - 1).setOpacity(0);
                vf.show(cardpane.getItems().size() - 1);
                FadeTransition f = new FadeTransition();
                f.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
                f.setFromValue(0);
                f.setToValue(1);
                f.setNode(vf.getCell(cardpane.getItems().size() - 1));
                f.setOnFinished(t -> {
                });
                f.play();
            });
            p.play();
        }
    }  
    initializeDeletionLogic();
}

private void initializeDeletionLogic() {
    VirtualFlow vf = (VirtualFlow) cardpane.lookup(".virtual-flow");
    for (int i = 0; i < cardpane.getItems().size(); i++) {
        CustomCard card = (CustomCard ) cardpane.getItems().get(i);
        Node cell2 = vf.getCell(i);
        addRemovalLogicForCell(card, cell2);
    }
}

private static double initX = 0;
private void addRemovalLogicForCell(OpioidCard card, Node cell) {
    card.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        initX = e.getX();
    });

    card.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        double current = e.getX();
        if (current < initX) {
            if ((current - initX) < 0 && (current - initX) > -50) {
                cell.setTranslateX(current - initX);
            }
        }
    });

    card.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
        double current = e.getX();
        double delta = current - initX;
        System.out.println(delta);
        if (delta > -50) {
            int originalMillis = 500;
            double ratio = (50 - delta) / 50;
            int newMillis = (int) (500 * ratio);
            TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(newMillis));
            translate.setToX(0);
            translate.setNode(cell);
            translate.play();
        } else {
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(300), cell);
            ft.setFromValue(1.0);
            ft.setToValue(0);

            TranslateTransition translateTransition
                    = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), cell);
            translateTransition.setFromX(cell.getTranslateX());
            translateTransition.setToX(-400);

            ParallelTransition parallel = new ParallelTransition();
            parallel.getChildren().addAll(ft, translateTransition);
            parallel.setOnFinished(evt -> {

                removeCard(card);

                ObservableList<CustomCard > cells = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                for(int i = 0; i < this.cardpane.getItems().size(); i++){
                    cells.add((CustomCard )this.cardpane.getItems().get(i));
                }

                this.cardpane.getItems().clear();
                for(int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++){
                    this.cardpane.getItems().add(cells.get(i));
                }

                initializeDeletionLogic();
                initX = 0;
            });

            parallel.play();
        }
    });
}

private void removeCard(OpioidCard card) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cardpane.getItems().size(); i++) {
        if (cardpane.getItems().get(i) == card) {
            cardpane.getItems().remove(i);
            updateNumber(this.totalNumber);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
        if (dataList.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(card.getName())) {
            dataList.remove(i);
        }
    }

    this.cardpane.layout();
    initializeDeletionLogic();
}
```

[image]

**WORKING DEMO OF ISSUE:**

```
package com.mobiletestapp;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.animation.FadeInUpTransition;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardCell;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardPane;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class BasicView extends View {

    class CustomCard extends StackPane{
        public CustomCard(String text){
            this.getChildren().add(new Label(text));
        }  
    }
    private static double initX = 0;
    private static void addRemovalLogicForCell(CustomCard card, Node cell) {
        card.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            initX = e.getX();
        });

        card.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double current = e.getX();
            if (current < initX) {
                if ((current - initX) < 0 && (current - initX) > -50) {
                    cell.setTranslateX(current - initX);
                }
            }
        });

        card.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            double current = e.getX();
            double delta = current - initX;
            System.out.println(delta);
            if (delta > -50) {
                int originalMillis = 500;
                double ratio = (50 - delta) / 50;
                int newMillis = (int) (500 * ratio);
                TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(newMillis));
                translate.setToX(0);
                translate.setNode(cell);
                translate.play();
            } else {
                FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(300), cell);
                ft.setFromValue(1.0);
                ft.setToValue(0);

                TranslateTransition translateTransition
                        = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), cell);
                translateTransition.setFromX(cell.getTranslateX());
                translateTransition.setToX(-400);

                ParallelTransition parallel = new ParallelTransition();
                parallel.getChildren().addAll(ft, translateTransition);
                parallel.setOnFinished(evt -> {

                    for(int i = 0; i < cardPane.getItems().size(); i++){
                        if(cardPane.getItems().get(i) == card){
                            cardPane.getItems().remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                    initX = 0;
                });

                parallel.play();
            }
        });
    }

    private static CardPane cardPane = null;
    public BasicView(String name) {
        super(name);

        cardPane = new CardPane();

        cardPane.setCellFactory(p -> new CardCell<CustomCard>() {

            @Override
            public void updateItem(CustomCard item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(item);
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        });



        setCenter(cardPane);
    }

    private static void addCard(CustomCard newCard){
        cardPane.getItems().add(newCard);
            cardPane.layout();
            VirtualFlow vf = (VirtualFlow) cardPane.lookup(".virtual-flow");
            Node cell = vf.getCell(cardPane.getItems().size() - 1);
            cell.setTranslateX(0);
            cell.setOpacity(1.0);
            if (!cardPane.lookup(".scroll-bar").isVisible()) {
                FadeInUpTransition f = new FadeInUpTransition(cell);
                f.setRate(2);
                f.play();
            } else {
                PauseTransition p = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(20));
                p.setOnFinished(e -> {
                    vf.getCell(cardPane.getItems().size() - 1).setOpacity(0);
                    vf.show(cardPane.getItems().size() - 1);
                    FadeTransition f = new FadeTransition();
                    f.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
                    f.setFromValue(0);
                    f.setToValue(1);
                    f.setNode(vf.getCell(cardPane.getItems().size() - 1));
                    f.setOnFinished(t -> {
                    });
                    f.play();
                });
                p.play();
            }
            addRemovalLogicForCell(newCard, cell);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> System.out.println("Menu")));
        appBar.setTitleText("Basic View");
        appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.ADD.button(e -> addCard(new CustomCard("Hello"))));
    }

}
```

This leads to the following output when adding and swiping left for deletion:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check with [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/), you will notice that the `CardPane` holds a `CharmListView` control, which in terms uses an inner `ListView` that takes the size of its parent.

So this should work:

```
.card-pane > .charm-list-view > .list-view {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

As I mentioned, the control is based on a `ListView`, so the way to provide cells is using the cell factory. As you can read in the control's [JavaDoc](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.4.0/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/CardPane.html):

> The CardPane is prepared for a big number of items by reusing its cards.
>
> A developer may personalize cell creation by specifying a cell factory through `cellFactoryProperty()`. The default cell factory is prepared to accept objects from classes that extend Node or other classes that don't extend from Node, in the latter case the card text will be given by the Object.toString() implementation of the object.

If you are not using it yet, consider using something like this:

```
cardPane.setCellFactory(p -> new CardCell<T>() {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(createContent(item));
        } else {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
});
```

This should manage for you the cards layout, avoiding blank cells or wrong reuse of them.

As for the animation, there shouldn't be a problem in using it.

For swipe animations, the Comments2.0 [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/comments2.0/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/comments20/views) provides a similar use case: A `ListView` where each cell uses a `SlidingListTile`. Have a look at its implementation.

You should be able to reuse it with the CardPane.

Try it out, and if you still have issues, post a working sample here (or provide a link), so we can reproduce them.

**EDIT**

Based on the posted code, a comment related to how the factory cell should be set:

All the JavaFX controls using cells (like `ListView` or `TableView`), and also the Gluon `CardPane`, follow the MVC pattern:

- Model. The control is bound to a model, using an observable list of items of that model. In the case of the sample, a `String`, or any regular POJO, or, as the preferred choice, a JavaFX bean (with observable properties).

So in this case, you should have:

```
CardPane<String> cardPane = new CardPane<>();
```

- View. The control has a method to set how the cell renders the model, the cellFactory. This factory can define just text, or any graphic node, like your `CustomCard`.

In this case, you should have:

```
cardPane.setCellFactory(p -> new CardCell<String>() {
        
        private final CustomCard card;
        {
            card = new CustomCard();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null && !empty) {
                card.setText(item);
                setGraphic(card);
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(null);
            }
        }
    });
```

where:

```
class CustomCard extends StackPane {
    
    private final Label label;
    
    public CustomCard(){
        label = new Label();
        getChildren().add(label);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        label.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Internally, the control uses a VirtualFlow that manages to reuse cells, and only modify the content (the model) when scrolling.

As you can see in the cell factory, now you'll iterate over the model (String), while the `CustomCard` remains the same, and only the content its updated.

Using this approach doesn't present any of the issues you have described, at least when adding cells.

**EDIT 2**

I've come up with a solution that works fine for me and should solve all the issues mentioned. Besides what was mentioned before, it is also required restoring the transformations applied to the CustomCard in the `updateItem` callbacks.

```
public class BasicView extends View {

    private final CardPane<String> cardPane;

    public BasicView(String name) {
        super(name);

        cardPane = new CardPane<>();

        cardPane.setCellFactory(p -> new CardCell<String>() {

            private final CustomCard card;
            private final HBox box;
            {
                card = new CustomCard();
                card.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                card.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
                box = new HBox(card);
                box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey");
                addRemovalLogicForCell(card);
            }

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null && !empty) {
                    card.setText(item);
                    card.setTranslateX(0);
                    card.setOpacity(1.0);
                    setGraphic(box);
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

        setCenter(cardPane);
    }

    class CustomCard extends StackPane {

        private final Label label;

        public CustomCard(){
            label = new Label();
            label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20;");
            getChildren().add(label);
            setStyle("-fx-padding: 20; -fx-background-color: white");
            setPrefHeight(100);
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            label.setText(text);
        }

        public String getText() {
            return label.getText();
        }
    }

    private double initX = 0;
    private void addRemovalLogicForCell(CustomCard card) {
        card.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            initX = e.getX();
        });

        card.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double current = e.getX();
            if ((current - initX) < 0 && (current - initX) > -50) {
                card.setTranslateX(current - initX);
            }
        });

        card.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            double current = e.getX();
            double delta = current - initX;
            if (delta < 50) {
                if (delta > -50) {
                    int originalMillis = 500;
                    double ratio = (50 - delta) / 50;
                    int newMillis = (int) (500 * ratio);
                    TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(newMillis));
                    translate.setToX(0);
                    translate.setNode(card);
                    translate.play();
                } else {
                    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(300), card);
                    ft.setFromValue(1.0);
                    ft.setToValue(0);

                    TranslateTransition translateTransition
                            = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), card);
                    translateTransition.setFromX(card.getTranslateX());
                    translateTransition.setToX(-400);

                    ParallelTransition parallel = new ParallelTransition();
                    parallel.getChildren().addAll(ft, translateTransition);
                    parallel.setOnFinished(evt -> {
                        cardPane.getItems().remove(card.getText());
                        initX = 0;
                    });

                    parallel.play();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private void addCard(String newCard){
        cardPane.getItems().add(newCard);
        cardPane.layout();

        VirtualFlow vf = (VirtualFlow) cardPane.lookup(".virtual-flow");
        IndexedCell cell = vf.getCell(cardPane.getItems().size() - 1);
        cell.setTranslateX(0);
        cell.setOpacity(0);
        if (! cardPane.lookup(".scroll-bar").isVisible()) {
            FadeInUpTransition f = new FadeInUpTransition(cell, true);
            f.setRate(2);
            f.play();
        } else {
            PauseTransition p = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(20));
            p.setOnFinished(e -> {
                vf.show(cardPane.getItems().size() - 1);
                FadeInTransition f = new FadeInTransition(cell);
                f.setRate(2);
                f.play();
            });
            p.play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> System.out.println("Menu")));
        appBar.setTitleText("Basic View");
        appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.ADD.button(e -> addCard("Hello #" + new Random().nextInt(100))));
    }

}
```

Comment: Jose, I posted a complete working demo of the issue. Let me know if it helps. Unfortunately, the cell factory method doesn't seem to work for me unless I implemented it incorrectly. You can see if you add a bunch of the boxes down below scroll, some of the content in the boxes disappears. If you have more than 1 cell and try to swipe left for removal, weird things start to happen.

Comment: Could it be because I am hiding the cells and then when the CardPane wants to recycle them, they are still hidden?

Comment: I've edited my answer, with an explanation of how you should do the cell factory. I haven't checked the removal part.

Comment: Should I add the removal logic in the cell factory itself? How do I delete the cell from the card pane item collection from inside the cell factory?  Would I need to make the cardpane static?

Comment: I didn't mentioned it, but yes, I removed all your `static`s. One step at a time. Make it work adding cards (including the animation), but comment out the removal call. Once this works (it should if you follow what I've posted), then you can focus on the removal part. For this one: you don't remove cells! you remove the graphic node within the cell (`CustomCard`). This includes animations for sure, as you can see in the Comments 2.0 sample (which you should try before).

Comment: I've added a working solution to the answer, check if it also works for you.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Jose.