# How do we look up the CSS class names for Gluon widgets?

Tags: gluon

I'm trying to manage a com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardPane. It's fine until the length of its list becomes scrollable. Then I get both a vertical and horizontal scrollbar around it. Giving CardPane a CSS class name to refer by doesn't work. There seems to be sub-components within it that I need to manage but I don't know how to refer to them by name.

Before answering that question, let me broaden the question so I don't have to ask it again later about another widget. Consider the GluonFX FiftyStates sample project. To apply CSS to the subtext of the ListTile, I see in the source code the following:

```
.charm-list-view .list-cell.header-cell > .list-tile > .text-box > .secondary-text {
    /* Headers secondary text */
    -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFFDE;
}
```

Okay, with that, now I know how to traverse down to specifically manipulate that aspect of the widget. But if none of the code samples showed this in their source, how would I go about knowing these hierarchies of CSS class names for a given GluonFX control?

If you don't know how to answer the more generic question I've asked, but you know how I can fix my CardPane problem, at least please tell me that, thank you. I'll have to abandon this GluonFX control for another one as a workaround otherwise.

**EDIT**

I found this advanced explanation related to CardPane by @JosePereda -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/46854083/16394182
It includes that CSS insight I was looking for:

```
.card-pane > .charm-list-view > .list-view
```

I seem to need to know more though about CardPane's internals as I wasn't able to resolve making the horizontal scrollbar stop.

I downloaded the SceneView application he mentions that lets us see into the widgets ourselves for CSS information -> https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view
But my application, running fine, shows an immediate stacktrace error when starting up SceneView, and SceneView keeps looking for a running JavaFX application, never finding mine. I suppose this tool isn't for GluonFX mobile applications, huh?

Comment: ScenicView works for all JavaFX apps, so nothing should prevent it from scanning a Gluon Mobile app. See the Readme for different options on how to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JoséPereda for the assurance to keep looking at making [ScenicView](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view) work. I was initially mystified by it and thought the issue may be something exotic. Turns out I just needed to update my GluonFX application's POM file with this one dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, I discovered the CSS class path to get rid of the unwanted horizontal scroll bar in my CardPane:

```
.card-pane > .charm-list-view > .list-view > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell > .card {
    -fx-padding: 5;
}
```

ScenicView is such an essential tool, I'm surprised it's not included in Gluon's docs as a standard developer setup.